# history.push not causing the location to change when ssr

Tags: react-router, react-router-redux

I have the following server code:

```
  const store = configureStore({}, history);

  const context: any = { store };

  const app = (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <StaticRouter location={req.url} context={context}>
        <Application />
      </StaticRouter>
    </Provider>
  );
// render app
```

And the following client side Connected Router:

```
    <Provider store={store}>
      <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
        <Application />
      </ConnectedRouter>
    </Provider>
```

I can see that the middleware is correctly hooked up and the `history.push` method is being called [here](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-redux/modules/middleware.js#L15).

But the browser does not redirect.

What would cause the browser not to redirect?

Comment: Is `history` there referring to `window.history`, or is there some other variable with that name in scope? Also, what's in your `configureStore` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out I had 2 different instances of history, 1 in the router middleware and 1 in the `ConnectedRouter`.

Ensuring they both had the same instance fixed the problem.

I have this file which I import it wherever I need it:

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';
import { createMemoryHistory } from 'history';
import { RouterHistory } from '../types';
const selectedHistory: RouterHistory = typeof window !== 'undefined' ? createBrowserHistory : createMemoryHistory;

export const history = selectedHistory();
```

And then make sure I import this file and don't make multiple copies of the history:

```
import { history } from '../../routes/history';
//etc.
          <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
```

Comment: have u ever used optional parameters with ssr, if yes how do we use ? (static router)